# Sum of Averages in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table created a report where there should be a field with sum of Avg.
Please find the below image 
[image]

I am getting the average but i need to sum the average to display A.

Comment: Have you tried sum(Reportitems!TEXTBOXNAME.value)? I never implemented it just guessing.

Comment: I am getting the error 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for the textrun 'A.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Comment: You can add expression as `=Avg(Sum(Fields!yourfield.value))` logicaly it is same that you get the sum of avg or avg the sum

Comment: @CoderofCode: Sum of Avg != Avg of Sum. As it has different row count under each group. Hope you understand. (I have currently changed the query with cross join to fix the issue I am sure it was not good soln however)

Comment: @ so your `SUM` is depend on the grouping of the first column let call it item that is `A`and `B` right ? if that's the case then you can add the sum of that group then apply the average so expression will be like `=Avg(Sum(Fields!yourfield.value,'yopurgroupingscopename'))`. And sorry for wrong suggestion as I was not able to understand what exactly you  need

Comment: @CoderofCode: your solution will be a fix if the number of rows of A1,A2...A!n is Equal.. Let me give u an example to understand. A1 has 3 rows rest all have 1 rows. Avg.A1=Avg(0,1,2). Avg.A2=Avg(2),Avg.A3=Avg(3),Avg.A4=Avg(1).. Now let us assume ur logic.. Sum of all values 1st = ([0,1,2],[2],[3],[1]) Which result in 9.. Now Average.. if its divided by 6 elements then 1.5 if divided by 3 elements then result is 3. Now Sum(Avg(A1)+Avg(A2)+Avg(A3)+Avg(A4))=7.. Hope you got it now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a custom function to the report, as outlined [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/20a400ee-85ed-4c46-a71e-356a43ea87e8/summing-group-averages-how-i-wish-variables-worked-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices)?

This person wrote this custom function:

```
Dim Test as double

Public Function Testing(Byval value as Double, ByVal reset as Boolean) as Double
   Test = Test + value
   Testing = Test

   If reset = TRUE Then
      Test = 0
   End If
End Function
```

At the footer of the group call `Code.Testing([value], False)` then call it again outside of the group with `code.Testing([value],True)` to reset.  Worked for me :)